# GSAP TweenLite Rotation but not animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a little new to using TweenLite. As you will see in the example, I have a div that I slide up which is all good, and I want to rotate the div itself so am using rotation 18deg however, can rotate this before the animation as appears it animated the rotation as it slides up. So I need to rotate out of view.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  TweenLite.to("#slide_one .background",
    0.4, // set the speed
    {rotation:"18deg", top:"0" // set the angel and end position
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.background {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  left: -100%;
  bottom: -300px;
}

.background.dark-blue {
  background: #071D49;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.15.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div id="slide_one">
    <div class="background dark-blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to know the solution you have to use set so does not animate

```
TweenLite.set(slide_one, { rotation: "18deg" });
```